# finding copies of Owen County, Indiana deed records?

Tags: land, indiana, microfilm

I need Owen County, Indiana deed records.  I would like to search online.  Due to covid worries I don't want to visit a family search center.  When will these records be available.  We used to travel to Salt Lake but can't do that either.

Answer (score 1):

**From the County**

Records are available online from the Owen County Indiana Recorder's Office.

> OWEN COUNTY RECORDS UPDATE
>
> - DEEDS: All Deed Books have been scanned back to 1819 and are in
>   the process of being indexed. We are currently back to the 1950’s
>   with even a few older ones that were indexed out of order. If you know the
>   book and page you can find the image for printing purposes on any that
>   have not yet been indexed. There are a few Exceptions and these are
>   any documents in Books 115, 116 & 117. For documents in these books
>   you will need to know the document number.
> - MORTGAGES: 4/7/92 Forward Indexed; 12/04/01 Indexed with Images
> - MISC:              August 1969 Forward Indexed with Images
> - Plats:               Indexed with Images (A Few Are Missing Due To Condition)

To see the options (either pay per view or by subscription) visit their [website](https://www.owencounty.in.gov/recorder).

**FamilYSearch Microfilm**

FamilySearch has deed records for Owen County in this collection:

- [Deed records, 1819-1890](https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/225354?availability=Family%20History%20Library)

The catalog entry notes that this consists of microfilm (28 rolls) of original records located in the Owen County Court House, Spencer, Indiana.

The Film Notes show the camera icon with a key, indicating that the records are locked. Attempting to view the images gives the following messsage:

> To view these images do one of the following:
>
> - Access the site at a FamilySearch center.
> - Access the site at a FamilySearch affiliate library.

FamilySearch is contractually required to abide by the access restrictions placed on the records by the record owners.  Records cannot be made available online unless the original record holders agree to it.

For some collections, it may be possible to get copies from FamilySearch's  [Record Lookup Service](https://www.familysearch.org/en/library/record-lookup-service). Keep in mind that there are restrictions on the service:

> Due to copyright restrictions, we are unable to copy large numbers of
> pages from any one film or book, and some collections we are not
> permitted to provide any copies from. Please also keep in mind that
> this is not a research service.

Are you a member of a genealogical society or historical society?  If so, perhaps a fellow society member might be able to make copies for you. (Facebook groups are a better venue for making such a request than a site like Genealogy and Family History Stack Exchange.)

Another option is to ask a volunteer to get copies of the FamilySearch microfilm for you from sites like [Random Acts of Genealogical Kindness](https://raogk.org/).

If you need more assistance than a lookup volunteer can provide, consider hiring a professional researcher.

- Association of Professional Genealogists [Member directory](https://www.apgen.org/directory)
- Board for Certification of Genealogists: [Directory of Certified Genealogists](https://bcgcertification.org/directory/)
- Indiana State Library: [Unaffiliated Researchers for Hire](https://www.in.gov/library/collections-and-services/genealogy/brochures-and-maps/unaffiliated-researchers-for-hire/)